# how to display date and time seperatly in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server-2005

```
DATENAME(MM,TripDateTime) + ' ' + CAST(DAY(TripDateTime) AS VARCHAR(2)) + 
 ', ' + RIGHT(CAST(YEAR(TripDateTime) AS VARCHAR(4)), 4) as TripDate
```

note:: tripdateTime is combination of date and time
here i will get the Date as march 31, 2011

but as simultaneously i want to get time(hours,minuts,sec) how can i get?? can u help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use convert to convert a date time value in anyway you like:

read docu here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054(v=sql.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
   ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), TripDateTime, 108) AS TripTime
```

to your query (Assuming that you want it as a separate column).